# ADODB connection state property

Tags: vb.net, adodb

I am working on an old project of my company, written in VB.NET (with no try catch block in whole app * sigh *). The basic problem is it leaves zombie process behind.

What I am suspecting is the DB call it is using i.e. ADODB connection object to query sql database.

```
 adoConn.Open("DSN=NameOfDatabase;UID=NameOfSA;PWD=password")
```

What I am thinking is to introduce a simple check for DB state. using

`adoConn.State` (int)

but I am not sure what are the possible values for adoConn.State.
I have checked on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adodb._connection.state%28v=vs.90%29.aspx but no information as such.

I am well versed with C# so i though it would be like

0: closed

1: Connecting

2: Connected etc.

Any such information (with proper citation) would be really helpful.

Comment: Intelisense shoud give you this.... adoConn.State = ADODB.ObjectStateEnum.adStateOpen  etc

Comment: Thanks @Fred, I am C# dev and Intelisense is stronger in that, it gives options of RHS too. Addicted to InteliSense. Thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`State` Property (ADO) indicates for all applicable objects whether the state of the object is open or closed. If the object is executing an asynchronous method, indicates whether the current state of the object is connecting, executing, or retrieving.

Returns a Long value that can be an `ObjectStateEnum` value. The default value is `adStateClosed`.

```
Constant            Value            Description

adStateClosed         0              Indicates that the object is closed.
adStateOpen           1              Indicates that the object is open.
adStateConnecting     2              Indicates that the object is connecting.
adStateExecuting      4              Indicates that the object is executing a command.
adStateFetching       8              Indicates that the rows of the object are being retrieved.
```

Comment: I think the return type is Int, After looking at it in Object browser it yielded:

Public Enum ObjectStateEnum As Integer
     Member of ADODB

Comment: `ObjectStateEnum` value is a `Integer`. I meant that `State` property returns a `Long` that can be an `ObjectStateEnum` value which is `Integer`